# Listing all enabled services centos 6

Tags: centos

I feel like this should be simple, i know the centos 7 command for it but cannot find the centos 6 command to list all enabled services.

Centos 7 command i have is

```
systemctl list-unit-files | grep enabled
```

I get a nice list off all the services that are enabled. I just need to get the same list from a centos 6 server?

Comment: This should also work: `systemctl list-units - - state=enabled`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use like this :

```
service --status-all | grep -E 'running|enabled'
```

OR

You can also try this :

```
chkconfig --list | grep '3:on'
```

Comment: Thanks i think the second one was what i am after assuming 3:on is the same as enabled?

Comment: Pleasure . Yes , if 3 is on , it is enabled for  run level 3  ( which is basically CLI ).

Comment: 3:on should work if your default runlevel is 3.  I've never seen a service that is turned on for runlevel 5 (graphical login) but not 3 (console login) so it should work even if you're booting into runlevel 5 by default.

For what its worth, in EL6, gdm is launched via Upstart so it doesn't have an init.d file. so don't look for it there.  Its in /etc/init/prefdm.